# Increase the speed of mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysql5

Are there any flags or tricks to speed up `mysqldump` for backups? Here is what we are currently using:

```
mysqldump --skip-opt --flush-logs --routines --triggers --allow-keywords --create-options --add-locks --quick --single-transaction --extended-insert --all-databases --events --default-character-set=utf8 | bzip2 -c > $BACKUP_PATH/$(date +\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H_\%M_\%S).sql.bz2
```

I noticed that `mysqldump` is running in a single thread, even though our MySQL server has 8 cores. Currently this command takes greater more than 20 minutes to run.

Comment: Just curious, how long does it take without the bzip2 step?

Comment: This is the type of thing where you have to analyse the system and find the bottlneck.  Once you find the bottleneck, then you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

bzip2 is not a good strategy here, gzip is probably 10x times faster, but both are quite CPU bonded.

To utilize your extra cores pipe into "pigz"

Comment: There's also [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/), pigz for .bz2.  If you have enough cores available it's plenty fast.

Comment: Switching to `pbzip2`, did not make much difference. The slowest part seems to be the actual MySQL dump, not the compression.

Comment: mysqldump doesn't support using support multiple threads out of the box, you might want to try to use something like this: https://github.com/luobailiang/mydumper